# Can I add custom levels to SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

SLF4J appears to support `TRACE`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN` and `ERROR` levels out of the box.

Is there a way to add my own custom levels?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The levels supported by SLF4J are fixed and cannot be changed. However, SLF4J supports [markers](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Marker.html) allowing infinite flexibility in tagging/categorizing log messages. All printing method in the [Logger interface](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html) have a variant which takes a Marker as its first argument.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - I'm using log4j as the underlying logger, which does not seem to support markers until v2.0 (which is currently still in alpha). I'm considering migrating to slf4j over logback instead, in order to take advantage of it.